# Python class argument error, num of arguments

Tags: python, class

I am getting an error of line 4 of circle.py when I try and run this

circle.py

```
import geometricObject
from math import pi

class Circle(geometricObject):
    def getArea(radius):
        return ((pi)*radius**2)
    def getPerimeter(radius):
        return (2*(pi)*radius)
    def toStr(self, radius):
        return "Circle: radius = " + str(radius) + " color: " + str(self.getColor()) + " and filled: " + str(self.isFilled())
```

geometricObject.py

```
class GeometricObject(object):
    def __init__(self, color = "white", filled = True):
        self.color = color
        self.filled = filled

    def getColor(self):
        return self.color

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def isFilled(self):
        return self.filled

    def setFilled(self, filled):
        self.filled = filled

    def __str__(self):
        return "color: " + self.color + \
            " and filled: " + str(self.filled)
```

I am getting a `TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)` printout when I run this code. I don't understand why it says I have given three arguments.

Comment: You are trying to use the *module* as a base class, not the class defined *in* the module.

Comment: I have read through that and don't understand what to change with my specific code.

Comment: `from geometricObject import GeometricObject`, and inherit from `GeometricObject`.